# jQuery Ajax post method not successful (not able to find the path):

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, servlets, web.xml

I am making an Ajax post method to send some data to my java servlet post method, but issue I am facing is that it is not able to find the path

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="outlet" id="myselect">
  <option>----------------------</option>
  <option>ALL</option>
</select>
```

And my jQuery (Ajax):

```
$("#myselect").on("change", function() {
  currentlyClickedOutlet = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "./src/com/touchpoint/controller/DateWiseOlWiseSales.java",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      Outlet: currentlyClickedOutlet,
    },
  });
});
```

And here is the file tree of my program:

[image: this the program pattern]

And on browser console it says error `POST http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/src/com/touchpoint/controller/DateWiseOlWiseSales.java 404`

If I am giving `URL:http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/DateWiseOlWiseSales` then its working fine  but the main issue if I ll use this URL then it is for local host only on deployment on server it can cause problem and I don't know why this is happening.

I am using eclipse (2018-09) in eclipse mars 4.1.1 by putting only the java class name it was working fine  like `URL:DateWiseOlWiseSales` it was able to find that class but not here in eclipse 2018-09.

here is my `web.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TouchPoint</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.touchpoint.controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.touchpoint.controller.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to come across as rude or condesending but if you have trouble with spelling and grammar, then you should try to use a service like [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) or [PolishMyWriting](https://www.polishmywriting.com/) as both services are free and can improve your writing a great deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in the Ajax URL field only the servlet name: DateWiseOlWiseSales

```
$.ajax({
       url : "DateWiseOlWiseSales",
       method : "POST",
....
```

And add the following to your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DateWiseOlWiseSales</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.touchpoint.controller.DateWiseOlWiseSales</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DateWiseOlWiseSales</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DateWiseOlWiseSales</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Share your web.xml please

Comment: i have include the web. xml file in my code...if you can guide me further with some knowledge it will be very helpfull :)

Comment: i have more than one java class for which i have to make ajax call like thgis..do i have to map all of them in my web.xml?

Comment: Yes. You can also use the WebServlet annotation (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-annotations.htm) directly into the Java classes

Answer (score 2):

You should always use a URL, javascript do not know whether your server is Java or PHP or whatever. You could use `/TPWebReport/DateWiseOlWiseSales` rather than `http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/DateWiseOlWiseSales` if your html page is in the same origin.

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "/TPWebReport/DateWiseOlWiseSales",
    method : "POST",
    data : {
        Outlet : currentlyClickedOutlet,  
    },
});
```

Comment: This way he will always have the constraint to deploy the application under the TPWebReport context.

Comment: you should always knows where your page's url, and you controller's URL, all web pages only recognize this, they don't know you Java file at all. If your page uses URL as `http://localhost:8080/TPWebReport/my_page.jsp`, you can also make the ajax url as `./DateWiseOlWiseSales"

Comment: @sirnino let me try this one

Comment: We don't even know what his page's URL is. I think he should learn some basic concept before coding. @sirnino

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like there's a disconnect between what your server endpoints are vs the local development environment.  You may be successful on the local host because you have access to that directory.  However, when you are in deployment, those sub directories may not be served up. So the net effect is that the .  becomes the deployment server endpoint and the server side code only gives up stuff that is exposed. I'm only looking at the snippet but if that's in a client page, then your java server would have to serve up the whole /src/com/touchpoint/controller/DateWiseOlWiseSales.java

Look at your server http handlers in the java server side code and see if that guides you to the problem.  Often your server will have to specificiall map the resource to the request.

Comment: what url should i type to acces my java class?

Comment: You have to move the java class to the folders that are public to the web service... You know like your images, css files etc..